# Duplicate a selected row and put the duplicate just below in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a Pandas dataframe like this :

```
id  A   B
0   2   2
1   1   1
2   3   3
3   7   7
```

And I want to duplicate the first row 3 times just below the selected row :

```
id  A   B
0   2   2
1   2   2
2   2   2
3   2   2
4   1   1
5   3   3
6   7   7
```

Is there a method that already exist in Pandas library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try

```
n=3
row = 0 
df = df.append(df.loc[[row]*(n-1)]).sort_index()
df
   id  A  B
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
1   1  1  1
2   2  3  3
3   3  7  7
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in method for doing just this. However, you can create a list of indexes, and use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`df.index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html):

```
new_df = df.loc[df.index.repeat([4] + [1] * (len(df) - 1))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   id  A  B
0   0  2  2
1   0  2  2
2   0  2  2
3   0  2  2
4   1  1  1
5   2  3  3
6   3  7  7
```

Comment: Congrats for your 10k!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `reindex` and `Index.repeat` to create your dataframe:

```
>>> df.reindex(df.index.repeat([3] + [1] * (len(df) - 1)))
   id  A  B
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
1   1  1  1
2   2  3  3
3   3  7  7
```

Another way:

```
>>> df.loc[[df.index[0]]*3 + df.index[1:].tolist()]
   id  A  B
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
1   1  1  1
2   2  3  3
3   3  7  7
```

A more generalized way proposed by @MuhammadHassan:

```
row_index = 0
repeat_time = 3

>>> df.reindex(df.index.tolist() + [row_index]*repeat_time).sort_index()
   id  A  B
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
0   0  2  2
1   1  1  1
2   2  3  3
3   3  7  7
```

Comment: I think `df.reindex(df.index.repeat([3] + [1] * (len(df) - 1)))` does not generalize well in case we want to repeat some other index than `0`. What do you say about using this: `df.reindex(df.index.tolist() + [row_index]*repeat_time).sort_index()`

Comment: @MuhammadHassan. I updated my answer with your solution and give you the credits :)